# Supporting Multiple Date Formats in ASP.Net MVC/Core

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, asp.net-core, backend

I work on an application, which just supported two formats - MM/dd/yyyy (en-US) culture and and dd/MM/yyyy (en-GB) culture. Now we support more than 10 formats and culture.

What is the best approach to handle multiple formats of date when your application is used by customers with different date formats ?
Fiddle Link - https://dotnetfiddle.net/5zauRz

Comment: Hi there! Your question is too broad. Here, on stackoverflow, we dealing with coding issues, so if you have a problem with your code (exceptions, unpredictable behavior, etc.) - edit your question or ask another one. You may also find this link useful: [ask]

Comment: Hi Jazb, I have updated it with Fiddle link - https://dotnetfiddle.net/5zauRz. My problem is, how should I handle multiple date formats for an application which is to be used in-premise in different countries (No-Cloud)

Comment: Always store in a consistent format and then Client Side code should covert the date to locale format. Like I would store time in UTC format.

Answer (score 0):

I think you shouldn't worry about the culture. Focus on the date formats.

There is no specific function that can parse any `string` as `DateTime` object. So you have to handle it manually.

My suggestion will be to keep all possible date formats as an array and try to parse your date as each format.

Delcare your array:

```
public static string[] dateFormats = {"MM/dd/yyyy","dd/MM/yyyy","MM-dd-yyyy","dd-MM-yyyy","MM.dd.yyyy","dd.MM.yyyy","dd-MMM-yy"};
```

And then try to parse in this way

```
foreach (string DateFormat in dateFormats){
    try{
        formattedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(dateValue,DateFormat, invariantCulture);
        break;
    }
    catch(Exception){   
        continue;   
    }

}
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5cx2UM)